# Depth > 2 possible with multisite?

Tags: multisite, directory

Is there anyway to create blogs with 2 depths using multisite? I want to have an installation in root and blogs with 2 depths. Something like:

```
/         - WP installation: root aggregate 
/foo      - WP installation: aggregate for a topic
/foo/item - WP installation: blog for an item
```

Trouble is that multisite only goes in one level. Other problem is that if I install in root, then I'm afraid that this blog takes everything bellow. So my questions are:

- Is it possible to do an installation of a blog inside another blog? 
  or
- Is it possible to get multisite to allow for 2 depth levels?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering your first question, yes it is absolutely possible to have one installation of WordPress running 'within' another (i.e. installed at example.com and example.com/child).  I have something like that running right now.

Comment: Ok, I will try this approach then.

Comment: *@tnorthcutt:* Have you running a multisite install that way? Or two multisite installs inside each other? Or have you running two standard, non-multisite installs into each other?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Multisite allows multi-depth sites (like, a child site of a site?), but there's no reason you can't have multiple installations of WP within each other. I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but I do know that WordPress always gives precedence to physical directories.

You will run into authentication problems with different installations, though.

Answer (score 1):

it's the aggregations that is the problem

Think about if you can manage what you what with categories maybe in single blog you could have multiple taxonomies drive the site that way

Comment: I agree: hierarchical taxonomies are the way to go.